# sleep() call inside gmock's EXPECT_CALL

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to do some sleep inside .WillOnce before invoking FuncHelper. So I need something similar to the following:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*_mock, Func(_,_,_)).Times(1)
  .WillOnce(DoAll(InvokeWithoutArgs(sleep(TimeToSleep)), 
                  Invoke(_mock, &M_MyMock::FuncHelper)));
```

Is it possible to call sleep() with an arg inside .DoAll? C++98 is preferrable.

UPD:

The solution is based on @Smeeheey answer and uses C++98.

```
template <int N> void Sleep ()
{
  sleep(N);
}
...
EXPECT_CALL(*_mock, Func(_,_,_)).Times(1)
  .WillOnce(DoAll(InvokeWithoutArgs(Sleep<TimeToSleep>), 
                  Invoke(_mock, &M_MyMock::FuncHelper)));
```

Comment: There is no need to define your own function, just use what STL has to offer. See my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you said C++98 is *preferable* rather than compulsory, first I'll give a nice neat C++11 answer:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*_mock, Func(_,_,_)).Times(1)
  .WillOnce(DoAll(InvokeWithoutArgs([TimeToSleep](){sleep(TimeToSleep);}), 
                  Invoke(_mock, &M_MyMock::FuncHelper)));
```

Otherwise (for C++98), define a wrapper function elsewhere in the code:

```
void sleepForTime()
{
    sleep(TimeToSleep);
}
```

And then:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*_mock, Func(_,_,_)).Times(1)
  .WillOnce(DoAll(InvokeWithoutArgs(sleepForTime), 
                  Invoke(_mock, &M_MyMock::FuncHelper)));
```

Note that here, `TimeToSleep` will have to be a global variable.

**EDIT:** As per suggestion from OP in comments, if `TimeToSleep` is a compile-time constant you can avoid the global variable:

```
template <int Duration>
void sleepForTime()
{
    sleep(Duration);
}

...

EXPECT_CALL(*_mock, Func(_,_,_)).Times(1)
  .WillOnce(DoAll(InvokeWithoutArgs(sleepForTime<TimeToSleep>), 
                  Invoke(_mock, &M_MyMock::FuncHelper)));
```

Comment: I didn't want to use a global var to keep tests flexible. However your answer suggests another solution. Thanks)) I'd create a template function with a value param. "template <int N> void Sleep () { sleep(N); }" It'd solve my problem.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't know that `TimeToSleep` is a compile-time constant. I updated the answer to incorporate this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer C++98 solution, I would suggest using `std::bind1st`:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*_mock, Func(_,_,_)).Times(1)
  .WillOnce(DoAll(InvokeWithoutArgs(std::bind1st(sleep, TimeToSleep)), 
                  Invoke(_mock, &M_MyMock::FuncHelper)));
```

Comment: I'm afraid that `std::bind` is not a part of C++98 standard.

Comment: You might try `std::bind1st` - that was c++98 solution - see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12  But you must hurry - it is already deprecated since C++11 - will be removed in C++17...

Comment: @Rom098 I forgot that there were only `bind1st` and `bind2nd` in C++98. I've updated my answer to use `bind1st`.

Comment: @PiotrNycz You are right, thank you for reminding me. As far as the deprecation goes, since he wants a C++98 solution, I doubt he will be upgrading to a C++17 compliant compiler next year ...

Comment: @MarkoPopovic @PiotrNycz I'd avoid using `bind1st` since it's deprecated now. Moreover the solution I choose looks more elegant and easy to read. But anyway I already tried the solution with `std::bind1st(sleep, TimeToSleep)` before I posted the question. This solution doesn't compile at all, GCC 4.8 fails with the error `"no matching function for call to ‘bind1st(<unresolved overloaded function type>, const int&)’"`.

Answer (score 1):

Define gmock *action*

```
ACTION_P(Wait, seconds)
{
  ::sleep(seconds)
}
```

And then use it in short, clean way:

```
EXPECT_CALL(...).WillOnce(Wait(3));
```

I think it is the most "gmockish" and the cleanest way to wait in gmock tests, especially if one needs to do wait in several places of a test.